# Powershell match multiline regex in file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have regex like this:

```
^(?m)[ ]{0,}<img[ ]{0,}(?:\n(?:(?!<img).)*?){1,}[[]src[]]=[""|']{1}(.*?)[""|']{1}(?:\n(?:(?!<img).)*?){0,}[>]{1}$
```

And I want to get the first line of match in a file, which matches this content:

```
<img
  *ngIf="amImg && amImg.sourcePath"
  [src]="amImg.sourcePath"
  [alt]="amImg.alt">

<p>asdasdasd asd</p>

<img
  [src]="amImg.sourcePath"
  [alt]="amImg.alt">
```

Regex works perfectly, I've tested it [here](https://regex101.com/)... 
Matches are 2 in this case:

```
<img
  *ngIf="amImg && amImg.sourcePath"
  [src]="amImg.sourcePath"
  [alt]="amImg.alt">
```

And:

```
<img
  [src]="amImg.sourcePath"
  [alt]="amImg.alt">
```

so the first match first group result should be `amImg.sourcePath` which has some linenumber 
the second match first group result should be `amImg.sourcePath` which has another linenumber

I've tried:

```
(select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern) | ForEach-Object{...}
```

and so on... but it doesn't even find a match...

Comment: You need to pass `-Raw` argument to read a file with all line breaks into a single variable, else, the regex engine cannot find matches the span across lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but how can I get the line number then?

Comment: Regex matching is line number unaware. You need to get the match line number separately.

Comment: I do understand.. but how?

Answer (score 0):

So after some brainstorming here's the result:

```
$path = ........
$content = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw
$regex = [regex] '(?m)^[ ]{0,}<img[ ]{0,}(?:\r?\n(?:(?!<img).)*?){1,}[[]src[]]=["|'']{1}(.*?)["|'']{1}(?:\r?\n(?:(?!(<)).)*?){0,}[>]{1}'
foreach ($m in $regex.Matches($content)) {
  $lineNumber = ($content.Substring(0, $m.Index + 1) | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
  "Found '$($m.Groups[1].Value)' at line $lineNumber" 
}
```